# mongodb create new record - if a field does not exist

Tags: mongodb

I am coping data from student table to "documents" table
Currently I have a condition  doc.isDeleted==true?true:false
How can I add a check to see if isDeleted exist or does not exist and treat it as false if it does not exist ?

```
 db.students.find({"studentPicture":{$ne:null}}, { studentPicture:1,studentId:1,isDeleted:1,_id:0}).forEach(function (doc) {

db.documents.insertOne(
            { 
                "className" : "com.model.ModuleDocument", 
                "documentId" : doc.studentPicture, 
                "studentId":doc.studentId,
                "documentTypeStr" : "LICENCE",      
                 "isDeleted": doc.isDeleted==true?true:false
                });
```

});

this seems wrong/will not compile

```
"isDeleted": if (doc.isDeleted == null){false} else if(doc.isDeleted==true){true} else { false }
```

Comment: Use upsert:true and $setOnInsert:{}  on field that doesnt exist, and default:false if empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
"isDeleted": doc.isDeleted === null ? false : (doc.isDeleted === true ? true : false)
```